# React JS useState for very quick events

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to write a container in React JS, I'm using [VisibilitySensor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-visibility-sensor) to check whenever my components are visible in the screen. Everything is working pretty fine, however the events of visibility sensor can come very quick, and I need to react to each of them. My goal is to draw an index of the page contents at the right of the screen and show the user what section is actually seeing. In some small pages it is pretty hard to handle.

Because this events comes very close in time if I use "useState" to set a value for how many of each section components are visible (once I have the visibility count I can get a ratio of how many of this components are visible against the total components per section), the state is not yet populated when my events come, hence I can not get an accurate count. So Now I'm using references (useRef) as they are immutable and preserve the state between renders (this save me from using global variables which doesn't die between page reloads). My question is what is the right way to achieve what I'm trying to do, don't think that using refs is the proper way to do this... Even though it works pretty fine ...

I tried with more complex states (All the sections in one state), more sparse state (one state per section), global variables (do not die on reload), local variables (reinitialized every render) and, finally, with refs which seems to work pretty fine ...

The code is not yet public and it is pretty long however I think you can get an Idea of what I'm trying

When using states I'm losing events, what does not happens with refs or global variables.

**EDIT:**

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

```
const getMaxs = (section1, section2, [ ... ], sectionN) => {

    /* Compute ratios for the sections, it is, given the components visible (the parameters) divide it for the total number of components per section and return a list of sections with the maximum ratio of visible components */

   return [sectionA, sectionB, [ ... ], sectionN];
}

const MyContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ prop1, prop2 ... }) {

   const [firstSectionCompsVisible, setFirstSection] = React.useState(0);
   const [secondSectionCompsVisible, setSecondSection] = React.useState(0);

   [ ... ]

   const [NSectionCompsVisible, setNSection] = React.useState(0);

    return(
    <Layout activeSections={getMaxs(firstSectionCompsVisible, secondSectionCompsVisible, NSectionCompsVisible)}>
        <Container>

                /* First section */
                <Grid container justify="center" id="IdFirst">
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                    <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          setFirstSection(visible ? firstSectionCompsVisible + 1 : firstSectionCompsVisible - 1)
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_1_FirstSection />
                     </VisibilitySensor>

                     <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          setFirstSection(visible ? firstSectionCompsVisible + 1 : firstSectionCompsVisible - 1)
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_2_FirstSection />
                     </VisibilitySensor>

                     [ ... ]

                     <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          setFirstSection(visible ? firstSectionCompsVisible + 1 : firstSectionCompsVisible - 1)
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_N_FirstSection />
                     </VisibilitySensor>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            /* Second section */
            <Grid container justify="center" id="IdSecond">
               <Grid item xs={8}>
                   <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          setSecondSection(visible ? secondSectionCompsVisible + 1 : secondSectionCompsVisible -1)
                        }}
                     >
                        <Component_1_SecondSection />
                    </VisibilitySensor>

                    <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          setSecondSection(visible ? secondSectionCompsVisible + 1 : secondSectionCompsVisible -1)
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_2_SecondSection />
                    </VisibilitySensor>

                    [ ... ]

                   <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                           setSecondSection(visible ? secondSectionCompsVisible + 1 : secondSectionCompsVisible -1)
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_N_SecondSection />
                   </VisibilitySensor> 
               </Grid>
            </Grid>

            /* Section N here...*/

        </Container>
    </Layout>
   );
}
```

I tried with a big state with an object for all the sections, which is even worst. If I do this way my states are not propagated quick enough so I will never get the proper ratios for the different sections, hence my index of contents won't display the proper information.

If I use a global variable instead of states to store the visibility of my variables the value of the global var will persist between page reloads, I don't want that because when mounting the component I receive events that I need to get the initial state of my page, and I loose some of them if I reinitialize the global var from a `useState(() => {reinitialise global vars}, [])`, and, a local variable will be reinitialized on every render, so what I'm actually doing is:

```
const getMaxs = (section1, section2, [ ... ], sectionN) => {

    /* Compute ratios for the sections, it is, given the components visible (the parameters) divide it for the total number of components per section and return a list of sections with the maximum ratio of visible components */

   return [sectionA, sectionB, [ ... ], sectionN];
}

const MyContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = ({ prop1, prop2 ... }) {

   const firstSectionCompsVisible = React.useRef(0);
   const secondSectionCompsVisible = React.useRef(0);

   [ ... ]

   const NSectionCompsVisible = React.useRef(0);
   const [activeSections, setActive] = React.useState([]);

    return(
    <Layout activeSections={activeSections}>
        <Container>

                /* First section */
                <Grid container justify="center" id="IdFirst">
                <Grid item xs={8}>
                    <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                            firstSectionCompsVisible.current = visible ? firstSectionCompsVisible.current + 1 : firstSectionCompsVisible.current - 1;
                            setActive(getMaxs(firstSectionCompsVisible.current, secondSectionCompsVisible.current, [ ... ], NSectionCompsVisible.current))
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_1_FirstSection />
                     </VisibilitySensor>

                     <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          firstSectionCompsVisible.current = visible ? firstSectionCompsVisible.current + 1 : firstSectionCompsVisible.current - 1;
                          setActive(getMaxs(firstSectionCompsVisible.current, secondSectionCompsVisible.current, [ ... ], NSectionCompsVisible.current))
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_2_FirstSection />
                     </VisibilitySensor>

                     [ ... ]

                     <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          firstSectionCompsVisible.current = visible ? firstSectionCompsVisible.current + 1 : firstSectionCompsVisible.current - 1;
                          setActive(getMaxs(firstSectionCompsVisible.current, secondSectionCompsVisible.current, [ ... ], NSectionCompsVisible.current));
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_N_FirstSection />
                     </VisibilitySensor>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            /* Second section */
            <Grid container justify="center" id="IdSecond">
               <Grid item xs={8}>
                   <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          secondSectionCompsVisible.current = visible ? secondSectionCompsVisible.current + 1 : secondSectionCompsVisible.current - 1;
                          setActive(getMaxs(firstSectionCompsVisible.current, secondSectionCompsVisible.current, [ ... ], NSectionCompsVisible.current));
                        }}
                     >
                        <Component_1_SecondSection />
                    </VisibilitySensor>

                    <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                          secondSectionCompsVisible.current = visible ? secondSectionCompsVisible.current + 1 : secondSectionCompsVisible.current - 1;
                          setActive(getMaxs(firstSectionCompsVisible.current, secondSectionCompsVisible.current, [ ... ], NSectionCompsVisible.current));
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_2_SecondSection />
                    </VisibilitySensor>

                    [ ... ]

                   <VisibilitySensor
                        onChange={(visible: boolean) => {
                           secondSectionCompsVisible.current = visible ? secondSectionCompsVisible.current + 1 : secondSectionCompsVisible.current - 1;
                           setActive(getMaxs(firstSectionCompsVisible.current, secondSectionCompsVisible.current, [ ... ], NSectionCompsVisible.current));
                        }}
                     >
                         <Component_N_SecondSection />
                   </VisibilitySensor> 
               </Grid>
            </Grid>

            /* Section N here...*/

        </Container>
    </Layout>
   );
}
```

Despite it works pretty well, actually it works as expected, I don't think this is the proper way to go, so any help here will be really appreciated ...

Thanks in advance!

Szz.

Comment: It might be helpful to post at least some code to help illustrate the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I'm late for work now, give me a few hours and I Will post some code, thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't thinks it's because "events come very quick". even if `VisibilitySensor` calculated really slow it would lead page froze while scrolling. can you make sandbox with minimum reproducible example? [offtop] if you apply [`IntersectionObserver`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intersectionobserver) per each  section as a whole you will not need to calculate percentage visible anymore(https://github.com/researchgate/react-intersection-observer).

Comment: Hey!! didn't know about IntersectionObserver, will give it a try. And maybe I'm not explaining myself properly. I think it is not only because events comes very quick, it is because of that and because state is computed based on the state itself. So if an event come it increments the variable, when the following event comes the state is not yet propagated, so the value incremented is yet the initial value of the state, not the previously incremented value, so I'm only seeing one increment in the variable, the last one.
If I can find the time I'll build a "minimal" sandbox example, thanks!

Comment: Hey, I finally solved it with intersectionObserver, great lib!, right now my states doesn't depends on themselves to be computed so my events can come as quick as they need! Thanks for your comments, and thanks to skyboyer for intersection observer!!. Not answering the question because I still don't know how to solve it actually ...